# Привязать популярные платежные системы к сайту на Django

Tags: платежи, django

Можно ли? Насколько это сложно?

Планирую начать разрабатывать сайт, выбрал для него `Django`. Одна из предстоящих задач - привязка платежных систем. Выполнима ли она в случае с этим фреймворком и как примерно это делается? Ранее не сталкивался. Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно, очень легко. Обычно платёжная система предоставляет всю необходимую документацию.

Comment: а язык разработки значит не критичен? Будь то Python, Ruby, PHP?

Comment: Конечно, совершенно не имеет значения.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть [django-robokassa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-robokassa/), если не устраивает Робокасса - есть и другие аггрегаторы, и отдельные системы, обычно все, что нужно - вывести форму и принять от ПС подписанный ответ.